# json image file not displaying in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, image

i have a json file in my server, i am trying to display it in my html website, i did the below code:

```js
var data = {
  "images": [{
    "bannerImg1": "http://molugu.com/yantraev/animation.json"
  },
  ]
};
data.images.forEach( function(obj) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = obj.bannerImg1;
  img.setAttribute("class", "banner-img");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "effy");
  document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div class="banner-section" id="img-container">
    </div>
```

but the json is not being displayed here, can anyone please tell me what is wrong here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Zubair Nazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14888629/zubair-nazar) the example file you used to explain these will not work. It looks like the example json file is an animated json file exported from lottie.

Check out this fiddle for a live implementation https://jsfiddle.net/87Lf6by0/

```js
const logoSvgData = 'http://molugu.com/yantraev/animation.json';
const animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('logo-bm'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  animationData: logoSvgData
})
```

```css
#logo-bm {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-bm"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.3/lottie.js"></script>
```

Comment: bro i want to display that json file only, the animation inside that json

Comment: Let me try it, hold on

Comment: Check out this https://jsfiddle.net/87Lf6by0/ to see the implementation

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` element is for displaying images.

JSON is a text-based, serialised data format. It is not an image.

Generally, to display JSON, you would request it using an Ajax API (such as `fetch`) and then generate some HTML elements tailored to the specific data format encoded in that JSON which you would then insert using DOM methods.

Comment: am new to this , can u please show as an axample or give me reference link

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
var data = {
  "images": [{
    "bannerImg1": "http://molugu.com/yantraev/animation.json"
  },
  ]
};
data.images.forEach( function(obj) {

   fetch(obj.bannerImg1, 
        {
            method: "GET", 
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }
    ).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       data.assets.forEach(function(image){
          img.src = image.p;
          img.setAttribute("class", "banner-img");
          img.setAttribute("alt", "effy");
          document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);
       });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
 

});
<div class="banner-section" id="img-container">
 </div>
```